# how to read appropriately on java document in terms of using methods

Tags: java

when I look at the java documents to see how to use methods.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()
I find two methods that confuse me, first one is

`static String  valueOf(char[] data)`
Returns the string representation of the char array argument.

that's the information I find on java docs, but I cannot find any information on how to use it, and how do I know I need to use `String.valueOf()` instead of `something.valueof()` based on java docs?

second method is

`String toString()`
This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

How do I know when it is to use  `Integer.toString()` or `something.toString()` based on the information provided by java docs.

Could anyone tell me how to extract those information? This issue has bothered me for a long time. Happy holidays^_^

Comment: "I cannot find any information on how to use it" What more information do you need? You call the method, passing in a `char[]` as the parameter.

Comment: how do I know I can use String.valueOf() because it only tells me static String valueOf(char[] data) Returns the string representation of the char array argument.

Comment: how to i know I have to add String. before valueOf()

Comment: If you don't add `String.`, which `valueOf()` method do you think it refers to?

Comment: my question is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a method in a class before you can call it whether by using an instance of that class or using the class itself if it is static.
In the case here, `valueOf()` is only found in the String class and it is static so you can only call it using `String.valueOf()`.
But that is not the case of `toString()` because it is not static and can be called through an instance like `something.toString()`.

Basically they seem to perform the same function but `valueOf()` is treated special a bit. Such that it can take null values but `toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException` if variable of null value is used.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find any information on how to use String valueOf(char[] data), and how do I know I need to use "String.valueOf()" instead of something.valueof() based on java docs?

It's very straightforward.  If you have a char array, and you want a String, you use this method.  If you have something other than a char array, or you want something other than a String, you use a different method.

> How do I know when it is to use Integer.toString() or something.toString() based on the information provided by java docs?

If you have an int or an Integer, and you want a String, then you use this method.  If you have something that is not an int or an Integer, or you want something other than a String, you use a different method.

For instance, Double.toString() converts a double or a Double to a String.

Generally, you look at the class you want to convert to, and find a method that does the conversion.  Sometimes, like the toString() method, the method is in the class you want to convert from.